# wake from sleep on password protected HDD

Tags: password, bios, bug-reporting

I have enabled ATA password for harddisk (in bios setup). When I wake laptop from sleep in linux (including Ubuntu distro) BIOS HDD Password prompt screen doesn't show up. You see only a black screen
How can I bring bios prompt screen?
Even when I except S3 sleeps from HDD lock (in BIOS setup) this problem still in place

Device: Dell Inspiron 6400

Ubuntu 21.10

Comment: Can you edit your post to include your Ubuntu version and laptop model? It will help us figure out the issue.

Comment: Most notebooks only ask for the BIOS password at the time of boot, not after waking from suspend. If your notebook has some additional features, knowing the version of Ubuntu you’re running on which brand and model of computer, as already requested, may help offer a solution 

Comment: @matigo On Windows, bios screen appears to ask HDD password on S3 wake

Comment: @ScarletNyaa Done